# How to set the default program or application for handling a given file type or url protocol?

Tags: windows-8, file-association

How can I change or set the default application for handling a given file type? What about for some specified actions, like "open web browser" and "preview image"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `control` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> now select the option **Default Programs**. Now you can select the option between `Set your default programs` or `Associate a file type or protocol with a program`. The first one will let you set the program default for the application which it can handle. And the second option will let you change the per file program.

[image]

If you choose the first option.

[image]

If you choose the option `Set this program as default` then it will be default for the applications it can handle. If you select second option then the option list will appear as in image.

[image]

[image]