# File associations for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, file-association

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to set default program or application for some kind of files](https://superuser.com/questions/494101/how-to-set-default-program-or-application-for-some-kind-of-files)

How can I change the default file associations of Windows 8?
Such as changing the default PDF reader to Adobe Acrobat, playing videos not on Xbox video but VLC media player instead?

Answer (score 1):

Type `def` in the Start Screen to open Default Programs, then click either of the first two links.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on a pdf file, Select Open With... then Choose Default Program.
[image: Default Program]