# How to change what application opens URLs (I cannot "set default browser")?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer, hyperlink

I am not able to change my default browser from Internet Explorer to Chrome because my company has internal tools which somehow break if my default browser is not IE. I work for a large company and the odds of being able to fix the functionality which breaks when I set Chrome as a default browser is approximately 0%. This is not an answer which will meet my needs.

I previously was able to view a list of all URLs and the default application which opens then and by changing web URLs to open in Chrome, I got 99% of this solution.

Since this, I have a new computer and these settings did not transfer appropriately.

However I cannot figure out how I was able to do this. I distinctly remember a list of all URLs and being able to set what application opens them.

Where can I view this list of hyperlinks and change applications accordingly?

Comment: If you are employed in a big company the better way is talk with your managers and ask them to allow you to use a different browser.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini that's not what I'm asking. I use Chrome all the time and am in fact posting here from Chrome now.

Comment: [BrowserChooser](http://browserchooser.codeplex.com) may work for you. Not ideal, but gets you closer.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://superuser.com/a/497043/19841

Comment: @DarthAndroid ahah! Yes, when you dig into Chrome's settings in the "Default Programs" thing you can pick all the URL protocols! Thank you.

Comment: @enderland Awesome! I'm going to go ahead and vote to close as a duplicate then.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the registry key located at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\http\shell\open\command`, but I doubt if this is different from setting the default browser.

Depending on what might break, you could change this as it doesn't change the default program for .html files.